# Remove duplicates and keep line which contains max value from one column - LINUX

Tags: linux, awk, duplicates, max

everyone!

I'd like to remove duplicates and keep lines with the highest value from one column (4th column) in a file with 4 fields. I must do this in a Linux server.

*Before*

```
gene  subj  e-value ident
  g1    h1    0.05   75.5
  g1    h2    0.03   60.6 
  g2    h7    0.00   80.5
  g2    h9    0.00   50.3
  g2    h4    0.03   90.7
  g3    h5    0.10   30.5
  g3    h8    0.00   76.8
  g4    h11   0.00   80.7
```

*After*

```
gene  subj  e-value ident
  g1    h1    0.05   75.5
  g2    h4    0.03   90.7
  g3    h8    0.00   76.8
  g4    h11   0.00   80.7
```

Thank you so much and I'm sorry if I asked something repeated! But I didn't find an answer for my problem.

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: Ive tried commands based on awk, as `cat blast_selected_split0_outfmt6.txt | awk -F'\t' '{if($1$3 in a){if($7>a[$1$3]){a[$1$3]=$7;r[$1$3]=$0;}}else if ($3$1 in a){if($7>a[$3$1]){a[$3$1] = $7;r[$3$1] = $0;}}else{a[$1$3]=$7; r[$1$3]=$0;}} END{for(x in r)print r[x]}' `

Comment: But it kept duplicates

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: wrt the awk command you posted - don't concatenate data to create indices for an array as that doesn't create unique indices. The concatenation of`a bc` = the concatenation of `ab c` = `abc`. So instead of using `a[$1$3]` and `$1$3 in a` you should be using `a[$1,$3]` and `($1,$3) in a`.

Comment: What should the output be if the same value appears twice as the max value for a given `$1`, e.g. if an additional line `g1    h3    0.02   75.5` appeared in your input? Should just one line be output (and if so which one - the first, the last, or based on some other fields value) or should they both be output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this, if it is no problem to get the output without the header:

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | sort -k1,1 -k4,4rn | sort -uk1,1
```

Explanation:

```
tail -n +2 file.txt
```

will remove the headers so they don't get involved in all the sorting.

```
sort -k1,1 -k4,4rn
```

will sort by column 1 first (`-k1,1`) and then by column 4 numerically and in reverse order (`-k4,4rn`)

Finally:

```
 sort -uk1,1
```

Will remove duplicates taking into account just the first column.

Be aware that `-k1,1` means from column one to column one, hence `-k4,4` is from column 4 to column 4. Adjust to fit your columns.

Comment: Thank you so much! Duplicates were removed, but it didn't cat the greatest value in 7th column. Actually, my file is bigger than example (it has 7 columns), I simplified to a 4-column file. So I used this command: `tail -n +2 file.txt | sort -k1,1 -k4,4rn | sort -uk1,1`. Is there something wrong?

Comment: @M.Sobreiro Updated my answer to add an explanation, hope it helps you. I think that what you want is `tail -n +2 file.txt | sort -k1,1 -k7,7rn | sort -uk1,1`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU ***[datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)*** tool:

```
datamash --headers -Wfs -g1 max 4 < file | cut -f1-4
```

The output:

```
gene  subj  e-value  ident
g1    h1    0.05     75.5
g2    h4    0.03     90.7
g3    h8    0.00     76.8
g4    h11   0.00     80.7
```

Answer (score 0):

An awk solution, but I like archimiro version for simplicity.

```
awk '
    NR>1 && $1 in arr {
        if ($4 > arr[$1][4]) 
            split($0, arr[$1])
        next
    } 

    NR>1 { 
        arr[$1][1] = ""
        split($0, arr[$1]) 
    } 

    END { 
        for(i in arr) { 
            for(j in arr[i]) 
                printf arr[i][j] "\t"
            print ""
        }
    }
' data.file
```

The result:

```
g1  h1  0.05    75.5    
g2  h4  0.03    90.7    
g3  h8  0.00    76.8    
g4  h11 0.00    80.7
```